# Working through Google Maps Engine API Tutorial - A bug in Create Table example?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-maps-engine

I've been learning Google Maps Engine API, working through the tutorial.
https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/tutorial

This was sailing along until I tried to complete the Create Table (1) interactive example.
The example gives a header and body, and you must enter the URL to create a table. My answer was exactly the same as the answer revealed in 'Show Answer':

```
https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables
```

But this raises the following error (thus halting the tutorial):

Sorry, that is incorrect. No results were found for your request. The asset might not exist, not a public asset, or it has been deleted from the Google Maps Engine. Please try again.

Response

```
{
  "domain": "global",
  "reason": "notFound",
  "message": "The specified entity does not exist.",
  "locationType": "other",
  "location": "draftAccessList"
}
```

Could anyone shed any light on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The message means:**

You don't have an accessList with the name `Map Editors` .

You could create such a list, then the request should work.

**The problem:** You can't create such a list anymore.

The usage of these lists is outdated, you may still use existing list but may not create new or modify existing lists. There is an article related to the access-control: [Access lists are no longer used in Maps Engine.](https://support.google.com/mapsengine/answer/4618526?hl=en)

**Related to the  `draftAccessList`-parameter:**

The documentation is partially outdated related to this parameter.

- https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/reference/v1/tables (deprecated)
- https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/table-create (required)

The parameter is not required anymore, but when you use it you must assign a valid AccessList. When you can't(because you don't already have this AccessList), **all you can do is to wait until the Tutorial will be updated**.

Comment: Thankyou. I will look for another tutorial in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

As Dr.Molle mentioned, there was a bug in the documentation. But it's fixed now! Thanks for your patience.

Comment: It's good to know that Google pays attention to developer forums! Happily working through tutorial now.